# Correct xml file format and apply it to all xml file in a folder and subfolder

Tags: xml

I have around 800 xml files with formt as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<playlist version="1" xmlns = "http://xspf.org/ns/0/">
<trackList><track>
  <location>../ppa/1/50/01 - Taknavazi.111</location>
  <title>Taknavazi</title>
  <creator>1</creator>
    <image>../images/Albumssmall70/Eshgh danad70.jpg</image>
</track><track>
  <location>../ppa/1/50/02 - Saz-o-Avaz - Daramad AbuAta.111</location>
  <title>Sazo avaz-Darama abouatta</title>
  <creator>2</creator>
    <image>../images/Albumssmall70/Eshgh danad70.jpg</image>
</track><track>
  <location>../ppa/1/50/03 - Saz-o-Avaz - Hejaz-JameDaran-   Hejaz.111</location>
  <title>Sazo avaz-Hejaz-jamehdaran-hejaz</title>
  <creator>3</creator>
    <image>../images/Albumssmall70/Eshgh danad70.jpg</image>
</track><track>
  <location>../ppa/1/50/04 - Saz-o-Avaz - KordBayat-Ouj-Esfahanak-Forod.111</location>
  <title>Sazo avaz-bayate kord-ooj-esfahanak-foroud</title>
  <creator>4</creator>
    <image>../images/Albumssmall70/Eshgh danad70.jpg</image>
</track><track>
  <location>../ppa/1/50/05 - Saz-o-Avaz - Dashtestani-KhosroShirin-Dashtestaniat.111</location>
  <title>Sazo avaz-dashtestani-khosroo va shirin-dashtestaniyat</title>
  <creator>5</creator>
    <image>../images/Albumssmall70/Eshgh danad70.jpg</image>
</track><track>
  <location>../ppa/1/50/06 - Tasnif - Bahare Delkash.111</location>
  <title>Tasnif- bahare delkash</title>
  <creator>6</creator>
    <image>../images/Albumssmall70/Eshgh danad70.jpg</image>
</track></trackList>
```

**and i want change its format like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<playlist version="1" xmlns = "http://xspf.org/ns/0/">

<item>
  <file>../ppa/1/50/01 - Taknavazi.mp3</file>
  <title>Taknavazi</title>
  <image>../images/Albumssmall70/Eshgh danad70.jpg</image>
</item>
<item>
  <file>../ppa/1/50/02 - Saz-o-Avaz - Daramad AbuAta.mp3</file>
  <title>Sazo avaz-Darama abouatta</title>
  <image>../images/Albumssmall70/Eshgh danad70.jpg</image>
</item>
<item>
  <file>../ppa/1/50/03 - Saz-o-Avaz - Hejaz-JameDaran-Hejaz.mp3</file>
  <title>Sazo avaz-Hejaz-jamehdaran-hejaz</title>
  <image>../images/Albumssmall70/Eshgh danad70.jpg</image>
</item>
<item>
  <file>../ppa/1/50/04 - Saz-o-Avaz - KordBayat-Ouj-Esfahanak-Forod.mp3</file>
  <title>Sazo avaz-bayate kord-ooj-esfahanak-foroud</title>
  <image>../images/Albumssmall70/Eshgh danad70.jpg</image>
</item>
<item>
  <file>../ppa/1/50/05 - Saz-o-Avaz - Dashtestani-KhosroShirin-Dashtestaniat.mp3</file>
  <title>Sazo avaz-dashtestani-khosroo va shirin-dashtestaniyat</title>
  <image>../images/Albumssmall70/Eshgh danad70.jpg</image>
</item>
<item>
  <file>../ppa/1/50/06 - Tasnif - Bahare Delkash.mp3</file>
  <title>Tasnif- bahare delkash</title>
  <image>../images/Albumssmall70/Eshgh danad70.jpg</image>
</item>
```

Please let me know that is there a way that i correct one xml file and then apply new format to all another xml files in a folder and its subfolder?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Personally - I'd be looking at `perl` and `XML::Twig` to read/reformat.

Comment: I don't know perl and XML::Twig

Comment: No, but this _is_ a site about coding. I'm merely suggesting an option for coding what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`XSLT`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) for that.

First, you need to create a stylesheet for the transformation between the formats:

*transform.xsl*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:pl="http://xspf.org/ns/0/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="pl"
>
  <xsl:template match="/">
  <playlist version="1" xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//pl:track">
      <item>
        <file><xsl:value-of select="pl:location"/>.mp3</file>
        <xsl:copy-of select="pl:title" />
        <image><xsl:value-of select="pl:image"/></image>
      </item>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </playlist>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that I've registered the namespace `pl` to address elements of the source xmls namespace. To avoid the `pl` namespace to get included in the output xmls I'm using `exclude-result-prefixes="pl"`.

Now you can test the transformation of a single file. I'm using `xsltproc` and `xmllint` which you will probably need to install first. On Debian/Ubuntu you need to execute

```
sudo apt-get install xmllint
```

For the test-transformation use the following command (Note that I'm using xmllint for formatting purposes)

```
xsltproc transform.xml file123.xml | xmllint --pretty 1 -
```

You should get the resulting xml like described in the question. If you want to save that into a file simply use output redirection in shell:

```
xsltproc transform.xml file123.xml | xmllint --pretty 1 - > output.xml
```

---

To transform all input xmls at once you need to write a little shell script. Lets say input files are located at `input` and output files should get stored at `output`:

```sh
for file in input/*.xml ; do
    output_path="output/$(basename \"$file\")"
    xsltproc test.xsl "$file" \
        | xmllint --pretty 1 - > "$output_path"
done
```

Comment: Thanks,this is the solution that i want ,but it seems that the software that you have mentioned (xsltproc and xmllint) work in linux am i right?                    and is there for windows also ,i don't use linux.

Comment: Start here: http://www.zlatkovic.com/libxml.en.html . (or use Linux, even if only in a virtual machine)

Comment: ,thanks so much i learnt lot of things about xml with your answer,and i accepeted your useful answer.

Comment: Hello hek2mgl,on internet i found a site of (http://www.altova.com/) that has a product under windows that change xml with xsl file for transformation but as i use the  transform.xsl file that you have written, in output .xml file it generate .111.mp3 ,would you please correct the xsl file?

Comment: In addition i want that change dir ppa to ppa1,thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need a tool from Altova. (And I cannot support that, since I don't have this software). You simply need `xmllint` and `xsltproc`. They are available for Windows too. Also I suggest to learn more about XSLT and try to understand the above example. When you understand it, you are able to modify it.

Comment: Hi, i have downloaded xmllint,please let me the modification,this is a part of my job,i will lose my job if i don't correct these xml files.

Answer (score 1):

The URI resolver for the Saxon XSLT processor provides the ability to open multiple XML files:

```
<xsl:variable name="all"
              select="collection('./?select="*.xml;recurse=yes;on-error=ignore')"/>
```

Then you can walk across all the documents opening a new result for each:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$all">
  <xsl:result-document href="...determine output URI here...">
    <xsl:apply-templates... (or whatever)/>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thanks,and would you please let me know that how can i modify the file extention in <location> tag from .111 to .mp3 ?

Comment: use document-uri() to obtain the file's name from the root node returned in collection() and then use replace() to change the extension and retrieve that portion of the name to use for your output URI.

Comment: Is this true for Saxon only or an XSL standard?

Comment: There are no standards for XSLT recognition of URI strings except for one URI string for collation for Unicode code-point order. It is up to each vendor to publish what URI strings they accept for collection URIs.